# How to hide a second name of user of message the same user in listview?

Tags: android, listview, socket.io, baseadapter, livechat

I try to do a chat with socket.io. I would like to that only a first name of user of message of the same user will  be visible.

For example:

```
     Username | Message

item:  Hans:     hello         (first message with name of user)
item:            How are you?  (second message without username)
item:  Look:     Thanks, good!
item:            you?          (second message without username)
```

Below code works sometimes good, sometimes wrong. While scrolling a listview sometimes a second username of the same user is visible, other time is hidden. How can I do the second name of user of the same user will be hidden and divider too?

Simple code:

```
package com.example.seadog.fb_dialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ListData> items = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    int id = 0;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.Title.setText(currentListData.getTitle());
        mViewHolder.Desc.setText(currentListData.getDescription());

        if (id != currentListData.getID() || position == 0) {
            mViewHolder.Title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            mViewHolder.Title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        id = currentListData.getID();

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView Title, Desc;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            Title = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
            Desc = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.descitem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably change it a bit like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    id = position > 0 ? getItem(position - 1).getID() : -1;

    ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

    mViewHolder.Title.setText(currentListData.getTitle());
    mViewHolder.Desc.setText(currentListData.getDescription());

    if (id == -1 && id != currentListData.getID()) {
        mViewHolder.Title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mViewHolder.Title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

You cannot be sure that the getView() will be called with sequential positions, like when you are scrolling up.

Comment: `id = position > 0 ? getItem(position - 1).getID() : 0;` this resolve my problem and condition changed on `if (id != currentListData.getID())`. Now I see that is good works. How can I be sure that getView() will be called with sequential? I need to be sure.

Comment: `getView()` is called on runtime depending upon which list item needs to be created/recreated. It will depend upon user action (scrolling), you can never ensure that it is called with sequential positions. You can safely use the code in my answer.